# Multiline Textbox with Segoe UI font indents text

Tags: .net, winforms

I have upgraded my Windows Forms .Net application from the default MS Sans Serif 8.25 font to instead use Segoe UI 8.25 as this is much easier on the eye and seems to be what MS themselves use.

However if I make a Textbox multi-line then it indents the text a few pixels. And makes it unaligned with other single-line text boxes, to the point where it looks like there is a space at the beginning of the text.

I'm guessing this is a fault with the MS controls / fonts.

Is there a workaround? This is .Net 4.5.2 (and older)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that I never noticed before and appears to be font specific.  As you stated, there is a left margin added for the multi-line textbox when using the Sergio UI font.

The base WinForm textboxes do not expose the ability to set a margin on the underlying native control, but the capability is there.

The code below demonstrates how to use the edit control messages **[EM_GETMARGINS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761590(v=vs.85).aspx)** and **[EM_SETMARGINS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761649(v=vs.85).aspx)** to retrieve and set the left margin.

For those interested, the default left margin using a multi-line Textbox with the Sergio UI font is five whereas the single line Textbox has a left margin of zero.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Const EC_LEFTMARGIN As Int32 = 1
    Const EM_SETMARGINS As Int32 = &HD3
    Const EM_GETMARGINS As Int32 = &HD4
    Dim res As Int32 = SendMessage(New HandleRef(Me, tbSingleLine.Handle), EM_GETMARGINS, 0, 0)
    Dim leftMargin As Int32 = res And &HFFFF

    SendMessage(New HandleRef(Me, tbMultiline.Handle), EM_SETMARGINS, EC_LEFTMARGIN, leftMargin)

End Sub

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Public Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByVal msg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32
End Function
```

---

Edit:  Based on the documentation for EM_SetMargins, the margins can be based on font metrics if the EC_USEFONTINFO argument is used.  This is probably reason for the observed behavior.

Comment: Given that this is a faulty MS control is there any effective way of reporting such that it will ever be fixed?

Comment: @Gwynge, you can try [http://connect.microsoft.com/](http://connect.microsoft.com/), but don't get your hopes up.  Most likely, it will receive a "this is by design" response, but you never know.  In reviewing the textbox code at [https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBox.cs,577a143ad3bbfb97](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBox.cs,577a143ad3bbfb97), I noticed documentation about new features for .Net 4.6.1 and newer.

Comment: Still an issue in 4.6. Logged with Connect (3122389). I'm familiar with the "it's a feature, not a bug" response as I dealt with IBM in the early 90s :o)

Comment: @Gwynge, I added a comment to your [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3122389/winforms-multiline-textbox-with-font-segoe-ui-8-25-has-extra-padding-on-left) submission to provide them with the details I discovered when answering this question.